# Error AADSTS650052 when creating AzureAD_Application

Tags: terraform, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I’ve registered a single-page-app + API server on Azure that allow Business + Personal account sign-in.

When I create this manually, a new user is given a prompt telling them their organisation admin needs to approve access to the application. However, when I create them using Terraform, new users get the following error.

> There was an error trying to log you in: 'AADSTS650052: The is trying
> to access a service server) that your organization lacks a service
> principal for. Contact your IT Admin to review the configuration of
> your service subscriptions or consent to the application in order to
> create the required service principal.

Here is the Terraform script

```
locals {
  app_base_display_name = "CompanyName- ProductName"
  app_display_name = var.environment == "prod" ? local.app_base_display_name : "${local.app_base_display_name} (${var.environment})"
}

data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}
data "azuread_application_published_app_ids" "well_known" {}

resource "random_uuid" "server_api_scope_id" {}
resource "random_uuid" "server_api_uri_unique_id" {}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "msgraph" {
  application_id = data.azuread_application_published_app_ids.well_known.result.MicrosoftGraph
  use_existing = true
}

resource "azuread_application" "server" {
  display_name = local.app_display_name
  prevent_duplicate_names = true
  owners = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  sign_in_audience = "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"
  identifier_uris = [ "https://${var.auth_domain}/${random_uuid.server_api_uri_unique_id.result}"]

  api {
    mapped_claims_enabled = true
    requested_access_token_version = 2

    oauth2_permission_scope {
      admin_consent_description = "Allow ProductName to access a user's name and email address."
      admin_consent_display_name = "Access user name and email address"
      enabled = true
      id = random_uuid.server_api_scope_id.result
      type = "User"
      user_consent_description = "Allow ProductName to access your name and email address."
      user_consent_display_name = "Access your name and email address"
      value = "access_as_user"
    }
  }


  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = data.azuread_application_published_app_ids.well_known.result.MicrosoftGraph

    resource_access {
      id   =  azuread_service_principal.msgraph.oauth2_permission_scope_ids["User.Read"]
      type = "Scope"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.oauth2_permission_scope_ids["email"]
      type = "Scope"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.oauth2_permission_scope_ids["openid"]
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }

  web {
    homepage_url  = "https://CompanyNameProductName${var.environment}.azurewebsites.net"
    logout_url    = "https://CompanyNameProductName${var.environment}.azurewebsites.net/authentication/logout"
    redirect_uris = [ "https://CompanyNameProductName${var.environment}.azurewebsites.net/" ]


    implicit_grant {
      access_token_issuance_enabled = true
    }
  }
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "server" {
  application_id               = azuread_application.server.application_id
  app_role_assignment_required = false
  owners                       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
}

resource "azuread_application" "client" {
  display_name = "${local.app_display_name} front-end"
  prevent_duplicate_names = true
  owners = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  sign_in_audience = "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"

  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = data.azuread_application_published_app_ids.well_known.result.MicrosoftGraph

    resource_access {
      id   =  azuread_service_principal.msgraph.oauth2_permission_scope_ids["User.Read"]
      type = "Scope"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.oauth2_permission_scope_ids["email"]
      type = "Scope"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.oauth2_permission_scope_ids["openid"]
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }

  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = azuread_application.server.application_id

    resource_access {
      id = random_uuid.server_api_scope_id.result
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }

  api {
    mapped_claims_enabled          = true
    requested_access_token_version = 2
  }

  single_page_application {
    redirect_uris = [
      "https://CompanyNameProductName${var.environment}.azurewebsites.net/authentication/login-callback",
      "https://localhost:6510/authentication/login-callback"
    ]
  }
}


resource "azuread_service_principal" "client" {
  application_id               = azuread_application.client.application_id
  app_role_assignment_required = false
  owners                       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
}


## to do
## 1: In AAD grant the app permission to the API "access_as_user" (done)
## 2: Same screen, click Grant Admin Consent
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can occurs when the Applications are not added in manifest known client applications.

so add appIds in known client applications of the manifest as it is multi tenant application.

```
known_client_applications = [
      azuread_application.known1.application_id,
      azuread_application.known2.application_id,
    ]
```

***Check the below code:***

```
resource "azuread_application" "server" {
  display_name = "companynameprod"
  prevent_duplicate_names = true
  owners = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  sign_in_audience = "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"
 

  api {
    mapped_claims_enabled = true
    requested_access_token_version = 2
     known_client_applications = [
      azuread_application.known1.application_id,
      azuread_application.known2.application_id,
    ]



    oauth2_permission_scope {
      admin_consent_description = "Allow ProductName to access a user's name and email address."
      .....
      user_consent_display_name = "Access your name and email address"
      value = "access_as_user"
    }
  }


  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = data.azuread_application_published_app_ids.well_known.result.MicrosoftGraph

    resource_access {
      id   =  azuread_service_principal.msgraph.oauth2_permission_scope_ids["User.Read"]
      type = "Scope"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.oauth2_permission_scope_ids["email"]
      type = "Scope"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.oauth2_permission_scope_ids["openid"]
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }

  web {
    homepage_url  = "https://CompanyNameProductNameenv.azurewebsites.net"
    logout_url    = "https://CompanyNameProductNameenv.azurewebsites.net/authentication/logout"
    redirect_uris = [ "https://CompanyNameProductNameenv.azurewebsites.net/" ]


    implicit_grant {
      access_token_issuance_enabled = true
    }
  }
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "server" {
  application_id               = azuread_application.server.application_id
  app_role_assignment_required = false
  owners                       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
}


resource "azuread_application" "client" {
  display_name = "kafront-end"
  prevent_duplicate_names = true
  owners = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  sign_in_audience = "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"

  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = data.azuread_application_published_app_ids.well_known.result.MicrosoftGraph

    resource_access {
      ....
    }

    resource_access {
      ...
    }

    resource_access {
      ...
    }
  }


  api {
    mapped_claims_enabled          = true
    requested_access_token_version = 2
  }

  single_page_application {
    redirect_uris = [
      ...
    ]
  }
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "client" {
  application_id               = azuread_application.client.application_id
  app_role_assignment_required = false
  owners                       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
}
```

[image]

Please check this [invalid_client - AADSTS650052- Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/28697/invalid-client-aadsts650052-the-app-needs-access-t)

Refer [Resource: azuread_application | Terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application)